# Do memory blocks allocated on heap have guaranteed alignment?

Tags: delphi, heap

I'm prototyping with FastMM powered Delphi 2010 and every time i allocate memory with `GetMem` resulting pointer is aligned to QWORD boundary. But should i rely on that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly specify it: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Configuring_the_Memory_Manager

Comment: Neat, thanks. Do you per chance know about older Delphis with proprietary MM?

Comment: Your best bet is to put FastMM in the old Delphi

Comment: @David Heffernan, rebuilding RTL amongst required dependencies is more likely a *worst* bet...

Answer (score 1):

OK, findings:

Quick test race revealed what default Borland heap manager shipped with D7 passes WORD and DWORD, but fails QWORD and PARA alignment testcases. Therefore either contributed MM or manual checks/adjustments is **required**. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Don't even think about LARGEADDRESSAWARE for Borland MM!

Comment: @David Heffernan, how it relates to alignment?

Comment: Completely unrelated to alignment.

Comment: You can easily write a wrapper around the memory manager, allocate some more bytes, and return an alignment pointer.